# Automatically Inserting Text Globally

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, shortcut-menu

Let's say I want this action to happen on any program whenever I press F10 (or some other custom key combination):

```
Paste the text: "Hello World!"
```

There's a similar tool in Windows called *AutoHotKey* but apparently it doesn't have a Mac equivalent.

Any idea how to achieve this on Mac?

Comment: Creating a service with Automator then bind it to a keyboard short cut could be an a solution

Comment: Matt, actually I've been considering Automator but I've never really understood how it works. Any idea how I can achieve this there?

Comment: See my answer below. I gave the full procedure to create such services and you them with the keyboard.

Comment: The MacOS native System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > Replace With shortcuts are a bit easier to add than separate keyboard shortcuts for each text: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192343/general-autocompletion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Automator :

- Create a new Service with automator
- Select *Service receives selected **no input** in **any application***
- Add a **Run AppleScript** action

Copy this script :

```
on run {input, parameters}
  tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "Text to type"
  end tell
end run
```

- Save your new service
- In System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services add a keyboard shortcut to your news ervice

NB: Replace "Text to type" by the text you want to add. Typing it will for example use directly the current style in apps like Word etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is no option integrated into MacOS, but I think the software [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html) is doing what you are asking for. You can specify shortcuts like "adr" to paste your whole address for example.